# Why Green Porcelain was Used for Chalkboards

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering, material-science, product-engineering, ceramics

This site: [https://www.businessinsider.com/why-most-blackboards-are-actually-green-and-not-black-2017-11#:~:text=The%20color%20change%20came%20in,likely%20to%20survive%20the%20journey](https://www.businessinsider.com/why-most-blackboards-are-actually-green-and-not-black-2017-11#:%7E:text=The%20color%20change%20came%20in,likely%20to%20survive%20the%20journey) states that chalkboards are often green because manufacturers started using a green porcelain coating on steel, making the boards more durable and lighter. But what made the porcelain green? I couldn't find an answer online.

Thank you! Also, if this is not the right place to ask, please let me know.

Comment: Because those “PC” folks did not like the term “bl-ckboards” so greenboards or chalkboards.

Answer (score 1):

A random walk thru a Google search suggests the following possibilities, or a combination of all.

1. White on Green is more 'pleasing' to the eye.
2. Green porcelain is easier to manufacture to a smooth finish than black.
3. Slate or black porcelain, being rougher, leaves more "ghost marks" after erasing than green porcelain.

Answer (score 0):

> But what made the porcelain green?

It looks better in pastel shades and is a popular colour in darker shades. It also happens to be the peak of the eye colour sensitivity curve.

The green was made with some kind of tinted material, and [some](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/504699/why-are-so-many-blackboards-green) claim it started in the 30's and became dominant in the 60's.

The coating materials and the substrates also changed over the years from porcelain to anodized aluminum and powder-coated paint or tinted silicon dioxide (Carborandum)  with many variations in between.

With improvements in chalk adhesion and dry erasing, the surface texture of the substrate and coating roughness make a big difference in write, read and erasability for contrast ratio and retention of chalk.

My rule of thumb when I attended uni. was a high static friction but low dynamic friction.  We had a special test to make the chalk stutter if held loosely and dragged at right angles.

Our EM prof. Dr Wolfgang Borner could fill up 8 boards worth every class with things like a derivation of Gauss's Law.

Comment: Sounds about right. One of my teachers was Dr. Maxwell, who made sure everyone knew he was a direct descendant of James Clerk Maxwell through an unbroken line of professors. He was a marvel to behold with the chalk board. He could fill every last inch of all the boards with copperplate writing and finish within five seconds of the bell. I suspect if you cut one inch off the end of one of the boards, he wouldn't have been able to teach.